# How to send an email from webserver using phpmailer

Tags: webserver, web-hosting, phpmailer, php

I can send email from my localserver. But when I am trying to send email from webserver then show the following message: 
Message was not sent
Mailer Error: Language string failed to load: connect_host

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require("class.phpmailer.php");

$name=$_POST['name'];
$company=$_POST['company'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$question=$_POST['question'];


      $mailer = new PHPMailer();
        $mailer->IsSMTP();
        $mailer->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
        $mailer->Port = 465; //can be 587
        $mailer->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
        $mailer->Username = 'info.dhuronto@gmail.com';  // Change this to your gmail address
        $mailer->Password = '*********';  // Change this to your gmail password
        $mailer->From = 'info.dhuronto@gmail.com';  // Change this to your gmail address
        $mailer->FromName = 'Client'; // This will reflect as from name in the email to be sent
        $mailer->Body = "Name :".$name."\n\nCompany :".$company."\n\nEmail :".$email."\n\nPhone :".$phone."\n\n\n".$question."";
        $mailer->Subject = $subject;
        $mailer->AddAddress('support@dhuronto.com');  // This is where you want your email to be sent
        /*$mailer->AddAttachment('attach_file/'.$_FILES["file"]["name"]);*/
        if(!$mailer->Send())
        {
           echo "Message was not sent<br/ >";
           echo "Mailer Error: " . $mailer->ErrorInfo;
        }
        else
        {
           header ('Location:index.html');
        }
?>
```

Comment: Some providers block the mailing function to prevent spam being sent from their systems. Which provider do you have?

Comment: I rent server from our local hosting provider company. eicra soft ltd

Comment: I recommend you try SwiftMailer.

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading all the PHPmailer files to your webserver. You might have forgot the language folder.

You may also have to set your language:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SetLanguage( 'en', 'phpmailer/language/' );
```

Comment: I have uploaded phpmailer.lang-en.php

Comment: now show following error message: Fatal error: Call to a member function SetLanguage()

Comment: I suspect your include path is incorrect. Check your config file.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to set the language in your script like

```
<?php
require("class.phpmailer.php");
SetLanguage('en','phpmailer/language/');

$name=$_POST['name'];
$company=$_POST['company'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
```

Comment: now show following error message: Fatal error: Call to a member function SetLanguage()

Comment: update:
Add a correct row. The results will be:
`$mailer = new PHPMailer();
$mailer->SetLanguage('en','phpmailer/language/');
$mailer->IsSMTP();`